# How to create a custom event trigger to invoke a lambda whenever a new bucket is created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda function in Python that I want to invoke whenever a new s3 bucket is created. I want to create a custom event trigger to invoke it. What would be the best way to go ahead implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a cloudwatch rule (see below) that triggers when a bucket is created or deleted and launches a lambda as its target.

In Cloud watch create rule > Choose
Service Name: Simple Storage Service s3
Event type: Bucket Level Operations
and select Specific Operations, specifying CreateBucket (and DeleteBucket) if you need it.

This will produce "custom" code similar to below.

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateBucket",
      "DeleteBucket"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could answer here, but have a look on this: [How to Execute Lambda Functions on S3 Event Triggers](https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-automation/lambda-function-s3-event-triggers)

Comment: Hi Marcelo, He is not asking for running Lambda on S3 put event, he is asking for execute lambda function for new s3 buckrt creation

Comment: Yes correct, I need a custom event trigger policy that I can setup in cloudwatch

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can monitor new bucket creation from AWS Config or AWS Cloud Trail services and call Lambda function for such event.